# C++ Operator overload conversion

Tags: c++

```
class Fraction
{
  friend Fraction operator+(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2);

  private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

};

--------------------------------------------------------------------


Fraction operator+(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2)
{ 
   Fraction r;        // declare a Fraction to hold the result

   // load result Fraction with sum of adjusted numerators
   r.numerator = (f1.numerator*f2.denominator)
                  + (f2.numerator*f1.denominator);

   // load result with the common denominator
   r.denominator = f1.denominator * f2.denominator;

   return r;         // return the result Fraction
}
```

Is there a way to make Operator+ add fraction (from Fraction class) with integer?

Example:

```
Fraction frac(7/15), x = frac + 13;
```

Comment: Of course that's possible. What exactly are you having trouble with? Please be more specific.

Comment: I can't get it to do the following inside driver.cpp because both parameters are type Fraction...........                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                         
Fraction frac(7/15), x = frac + 13;

Comment: This isn't any clearer in the comment than it is in the question itself.

Comment: I can't get it to do the following inside driver.cpp because both parameters are type Fraction.   Note: The 13 is not type Fraction...........                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                         
Fraction frac(7/15), x = frac + 13;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, although I wouldn't do it that way.

Presumably (in your real code) you have a constructor for `Fraction` that takes two arguments: a numerator and a denominator. Make the denominator a default argument set to 1.

Then you will not need any more overloads to `+`, or any extra overloads that you intend to support over time (e.g. `-`, `*`, &c.).